# Django Showing Error while running manage.py file

Tags: python, django

while running my .....python manage.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 364, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
>   line 27, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 94, in create
>       module = import_module(entry)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named djorm_pgtrgm

Comment: Have you installed `djorm-ext-pgtrgm `?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that django is installed for the right version of python (it seems you're running python 2, check if you only installed for pyhton 3, or the other way around)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the command `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

First check for clear installation of django. And fire correct query at correct path. Open your cmd , go to the path were you placed your `manage.py` file is. And then fire query `python manage.py runserver`.